# Cache for logged-in user?

Tags: 8, database, caching

I have created simple form and page to list records on form via Custom Drupal 8 Module. This form is accessible to only logged-in users with some specific role. It looks like screenshot. Whenever I submit new entry it lists record in via theme table for admin user but it does not appear for other logged-in users until I clear cache manually.

Please suggest, Thanks!

To display Records :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_form\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DisplayRecords extends ControllerBase {

  public function DisplayCustomRecords() {

    // Display theme table

    $table_header = [
      'name' => t('Name'),
      'mobilenumber' => t('Phone Number'),
      'email' => t('Email'),
      'age' => t('Age'),
      'gender' => t('Gender')
    ];

    $results = \Drupal::database()->select('custom_for_data')
      ->fields('custom_for_data', [
        'name',
        'mobilenumber',
        'email',
        'age',
        'gender'
      ])
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($results as $res) {
      $formatted_age = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format(
        $res->age, 'custom', 'Y-m-d'
      );
      $rows[] = [
        'name' => $res->name,
        'mobilenumber' => $res->mobilenumber,
        'email' => $res->email,
        'age' => $formatted_age,
        'gender' => $res->gender
      ];
    }

    $form['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $table_header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#empty' => t('No users found'),
    ];

    return $form;

  }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don’t add solutions to questions - that’s why we have answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: You need to define a cache tag that you can invalidate when a record is created, updated or deleted.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays for a lot of documentation on this.

I'd also recommend to look into using an entity type for this instead of a custom table. A bit of effort at first, but you get a ton of functionality with that, including default cache tags and for example views integration, so you can build searchable, sortable listings like that through views.

Comment: I will look into details, thanks. As from your answers it sounds like recommended way is to create entity to store custom records rather than custom tables ? please suggest, that will be great if some more explanation will be added.

Comment: `sounds like recommended way is to create entity to store custom records rather than custom tables` @jas Yes, that is what he is suggesting.

Comment: @jas Better yet, you could build your form using the [https://www.drupal.org/project/webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and then create a View to display the results of the form.

Comment: Better depends on the use case. Webform is good at building a public form and then storing submissions that can be viewed by admins. I wouldn't use it for actual content that you want to manage. But yes, webform might be a good alternative for this use case as well but hard to say without knowing the whole use case :)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to learn how insert and select queries work with custom form so was working this way. By adding `options:no_cache: TRUE` its working now and records display without cache. Update added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to learn how insert and select queries work with custom form so was using this way . By adding options:no_cache: TRUE its working now.

```
DisplayRecords:
    path: 'list/custom/records'
    defaults:
      '_title': 'Custom Records List'
      '_controller': 'Drupal\custom_form\Controller\DisplayRecords::DisplayCustomRecords'
    requirements:
       _permission: 'access_custom_records_display'
    options:
      no_cache: TRUE // with this line cache stops on page
```